# I try one work with the if else but did not get properly result

Tags: php, laravel

It's Code that i use

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM districts";

$result = $mysqli->query($application->districts->name);

if ($result) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo 'found';
    } else {
        echo 'not found';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error();
}

$result = $mysqli->query($application->districts->name);
```

when i use this code its show me error You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'Patiala' at line 1

but on error its show me district name. it's my table link

https://i.ibb.co/fkW2Jwb/Capture.png

Now i want if user already selected id 26 or 27 then if statement will print and if user select other than this then else statement will print .

`$application->districts->name` (This show me the user already select data but on error --- when i use this code its show me error

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
> corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use
> near 'Patiala' at line 1 --- Patiala already selected by user.

Please help me in this

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM districts";

$result = $mysqli->query($application->districts->name);

if ($result) {
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
        echo 'found';
    } else {
        echo 'not found';
    }
} else {
    echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error();
}
```

Comment: It seems that youdon't use Laravel's ORM based on models in order to access your database. Btw you should pass your query as a parameter like `$result = $mysqli->query($query);` and if you have to filter by your district name just change your query in order to filter your results

Comment: $mysqli->query() method of a mysqli_connection just runs the query that you pass as a parameter and returns a result object that allows you to fetch every row

Comment: Useful guide: https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli . But if you're using Laravel, why are you not using Laravel's ready-made database functionality? https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/database

Comment: As others have said, `$application->districts->name` is clearly not a variable containing a valid SQL query.

Answer (score 0):

That's because you don't pass the query in the ->query method but only a string that is not a proper sql query.

Something like this should work.

```php
$query = "SELECT * FROM districts where name = '{$application->districts->name}' ";

$result = $mysqli->query($query);
```

Comment: Its work fine ! Now i want one if condition 

if ($result) 
{ 
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) { echo 'found'; } 
    else { echo 'not found'; } } 
    else { echo 'Error: ' . mysqli_error(); 
}

Its show me Found on output becuase districts are in database. Now in if condition i put a condition.

https://i.ibb.co/fkW2Jwb/Capture.png (Column Image)

If user select first or second or third column district then its show found and all other columns show not found